# Why does Go allow a struct to implement an unexported interface present in a different package?

Tags: go, interface, go-interface

I wrote a sample code to understand how the **unexported** **interface** works. In the below example, I have declared the **unexported repoInterface** in the **service** package.

**TestRepo** struct in the **repo** package **implements** the **unexported repoInterface** without any issues.

```
Code structure
repo
  repo.go
service
  service.go
main.go
```

service.go

```
// service/service.go

// this is the interface which the TestRepo struct implements in repo package
type repoInterface interface{
    GetName() string
}

type TestService struct{
    repo repoInterface
}

func NewTestService(r repoInterface) TestService {
    return TestService{
       repo: r,
    }
}

func (s TestService) GetName() string {
    return s.repo.GetName()
}
```

repo/repo.go

```
// repo/repo.go
type TestRepo struct{
    name string
}

func NewTestRepo(name string) TestRepo {
    return TestRepo{
        name: name,
    }
}

// implements repoInterface present in service package
func (r TestRepo) GetName() string {
    return r.name
}
```

main.go

```
func main() {
    testRepo := repo.NewTestRepo("hello")
    testService := service.NewTestService(testRepo)
    fmt.Println(testService.GetName())
}

// Output
// hello
```

*My assumption so far:*

> This isn't possible since repo and service
> are different packages.

> TestRepo struct present in repo package cannot implement the Unexported interface present in the service package.
> This is the reason why we export interfaces.

Now I realized that this is not true and my understanding is wrong.

**Question:**

Why does Go allow to implement an unexported interface present in a different package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`service.NewTestService` package function requires any value that implements the [type](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Interface_types) `interface{ GetName() string }`.

`repo` package [exports](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) a [type](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Types) `TestRepo` which exposes a method `GetName() string`.

Upon passing the `repo.TestRepo` to the `service.NewTestService` function like in `service.NewTestService(testRepo)`, the value implements the interface by providing the expected [method set](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Method_sets).

All good.

That the type `service.repoInterface` [declares](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope) a not exported [identifier](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Identifiers) only discriminates the packages that can use that interface name.

I have reproduced your example on the play https://go.dev/play/p/bp6z2HjwdLS

---

An interface type declaration containing a not exported identifier is a [sealed](https://blog.chewxy.com/2018/03/18/golang-interfaces/#sealed-interfaces) interface.

Those sealed interfaces can not be implemented by a foreign package.

It can be a not exported method name like in

```
type Fooer interface {
    Foo() 
    sealed()
}
```

Try here https://go.dev/play/p/3Syh7R0uS-q

It can also declare a method using a not exported argument type,

```golang
type Foo interface {
    GetName() string
    GetName2() sealed
}

type sealed int
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. 
Could explain more on the discrimination part


`That the type service.repoInterface declares a not exported identifier only discriminates the packages that can use that interface name.`

Comment: @syedalisait Like the spec says `An identifier may be exported to permit access to it from another package.`. Does it answer your question ? the identifier in question being `repoInterface`